# Deploying an ASP.NET 5 Web App through ARM not working

Tags: azure-resource-manager, asp.net5

I'm migrating an ASP.NET 5 Web App from manually deploying in Visual Studio to deploying through an ARM template. I can successfully provision the website and the deploy claims to succeed, but whenever I hit my endpoint I get a 404. It doesn't seem to be a configuration issue, as if I deploy the same web app into the same container through VS it works as expected.

Browsing through the files on the site, the only difference I can see is that there's no web.config when published through ARM, and I'm wondering if that might cause it.

The way the deploy seems to work is that ARM is calling "dnu pack" on my xproj to create a nupkg, and that deliberately strips out the web.config file. I get the following message:

```
The following commands will not be exported for global install: web.
```

I can't see any way of forcing "dnu pack" to include web.config.

Most of the documentation I can find refers to using a .zip file to upload, but that seems to be only for older versions of ASP.NET. Anyone got any pointers?